# Modular VUEX structure, [vuex] unknown getter:

Tags: vuex

When I try to get `getters` of the module, this error returns `[vuex] unknown getter:`  I tried to follow the [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#binding-helpers-with-namespace). But somewhere there is a problem and couldn't figure it out.

How I try to get the getters in component.

```
computed:{
   ...mapGetters({coords: "project/get_coords"}),
```

**structure tree:**

main store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({})
```

and project module has it's own `store`

the project/store.js

```
import store from "@/store"
import map from "./modules/map"

store.registerModule("project", {map})
```

and inside the store/ModuleNameOfStore/getters,mutations etc..

```
import getters from './getters';
import mutations from './mutations';

const state = {
  coords: [...],
};

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  mutations,
};
```

and for an example here is the `getters.js`

```
const get_coords = (state) => {
  return state.coords
}

export default {
  get_coords,
}
```

Additionally here is the Vue Devtools:vuex debug.
[image]

Can anyone point out the problem here.

Comment: Can you add contents of `modules/map.js` or is that what you mean by "store/ModuleNameOfStore/getters,mutations"?

Comment: sorry for not being clear over there. **ModuleNameOfStore** is for example `/map/` folder and inside that there is `index.js` or you can say it `map.js` and above in the question I shared the contents of that file.  @MikeW